# Outlook - How to add custom information sent with an email

Tags: c#, winforms, email, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm querying the possibility of including custom email information that will be able to be displayed alongside an email like the example below.

**Example:**

This screenshot shows the information that hints at the user to view the email in a web browser.

[image: Example of information sent with an email]

I'm currently using C# Windows Forms to create this addin and I can't seem to find any way about doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a X-header on the outgoing email, but Outlook (any other mail client) won't display anything they don't know about.

Comment: That's a shame so say if I sent an email to someone accessing it through Google Mail the information won't be displayed?

Comment: Google only knows about subject, recipients, sender, etc. What would it display something it known nothing about?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to customize the GUI in your email clients rather than include extra data in the email message. For Outlook GUI customization there are some tutorials out there:

https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/04/29/outlook-ui-customizing/

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/VSTO-How-to-Customize-4b9d3401